# how can browser special/weired characters handled in java server side?

Tags: javascript, java, string, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

I have to process/work with certain chars from client side to java side. I am unable to identify either the image chars type/language.
I would like to know what is these chars interpret and how we can handle this char as String variable in java ?

Fyr, Image attached[image: image chars]

Comment: It will be `utf-8` strings.

Comment: First you need to tell Java the unicode these characters are from. UTF-8 is commonly used. These Chinese characters for example can be encoded using 2-4 bytes depending the unicode your using. Java will need to understand the unicode as well before it able to convert into bytes of String.

Comment: I am using utf-8 encoding on server class,client, tomcat.  I sent this chars from client to server but when I try to receive the images, they are broken or I get "?" marks